# Error searching for :all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables, search, textbox

I am currently trying to create a search method. I have a database all setup; however, I am running into the errors:

`ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ArticlesController#index`

and:

`Couldn't find Article with 'id'=all`

Here is the pertinent code:

`Articles_controller.rb`

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @articles = Article.all

    @articles = Article.search(params[:id])
  end

  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:search])
  end

  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end

  def edit
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @article = Article.new(params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text))

    if @article.save
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])

    if @article.update(article_params)
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @article.destroy

    redirect_to articles_path
  end

  private
    def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
    end
end
```

`article.rb`

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :title, presence: true,
                    length: { minimum: 5 }

    def self.search(search)
    if search
        @article = Article.find(:all, :conditions => ['name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
    else
        @article = Article.find(:all)
    end
    end

end
```

`index.rb`

```
<h1>Listing articles</h1>

<%= link_to 'New article', new_article_path %> 

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Text</th>
    <th colspan="3"></th>
  </tr>

  <% @articles.each do |article| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= article.title %></td>
      <td><%= article.text %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Show', article_path(article) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_path(article) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', article_path(article),
              method: :delete,
              data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>


  <%= form_tag articles_path, :method => 'get' do %>
     <p>
        <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
        <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
     </p>
 <% end %>

</table>
```

Sorry for all the code to look through.  The errors I am getting are from running localhost:3000/articles, where I receive these error messages from the server.  I should note that I am still very new to both Ruby and Ruby on Rails; however, I aim to learn and find seeing proper code helps me quite significantly (I am dyslexic and tend to be a visual learner).

I truly appreciate your help, thanks in advance.

Comment: `@article = Article.find(:all)` what is this in the model ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think find can not take :all. the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) says

"Using the find method, you can retrieve the object corresponding to the specified **primary key** that matches any supplied options. I think this is enough

```
Article.where('name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
```

or if you find all the articles

```
Article.all
```

Comment: One other question, during my search, the back-end looks like this `Started GET "/articles?search=asd&utf8=%E2%9C%93" for ::1 at 2016-03-14 08:17:11 -0400
Processing by ArticlesController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"search"=>"asd", "utf8"=>"✓"}
  Article Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles"
  Rendered articles/index.html.erb within layouts/application (1.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 15ms (Views: 14.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)`

it appears the search is not actually searching, what am I missing?

Comment: I am currently searching for an item in the database called `asd` however, when I search for it I get the aforementioned message (in the back end of the server), as well as the entire list of what is in the database, it looks like it is listing everything from the articles database instead of just the searched item or the searched item along with the rest of the database.

Comment: here is the database code `class CreateArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :articles do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :text

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
`

Answer (score -1):

Why do you have `@articles = Article.search(params[:id])` in the index method?

Also, the stack trace will tell you exactly on which line the error occurs